# Why my API is returning JSON format on Header "accept: application/xml"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an API with OData integration returning response JSON and XML format, but why is my API returning JSON format instead of XML format on the header `accept: application/xml`

This is my `Program.cs` with Odata and XML  formatter.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

...

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().OrderBy().Count());

builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
});

....
```

And this is the controller I've been testing on.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace OData.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [FormatFilter]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        [EnableQuery]
        [FormatFilter]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

what seems to be the problem with my controller?

Comment: `options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader` / `config.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable` ?

Comment: that's the problem when I include that its giving me this error or warning `warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      No output formatter was found for content types 'application/json, application/xml, application/xml' to write the response.`

Comment: Rather than relying on the `Accept` header it's easier to specify a `{format}` route parameter with `[FormatFilter]`. Make sure to populate `options.FormatterMappings`.

Comment: Also, while `[Produces]` will populate your swagger docs, `Ok()` doesn't use it. Given how https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/de3019b7dab5b5995942db1fbec6aa466c4af34c/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultOutputFormatterSelector.cs#L56 is implemented, you could explicitly populate the `OkObjectResult.Formatters` & `OkObjectResult.ContentTypes` in a helper / base type method.

Comment: using `{format}` returning only `{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "00-2c05ce02617b73268d5aafbac0c6cddb-f2698905d1b144bd-00"
}`

Comment: can you provide me with a project that has XML and JSON responses with OData @JeremyLakeman

Comment: just tested it out again recently but the only problem actually that is not working on getting the XML format with OData is the `$select` and `$epand` method @JeremyLakeman

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
```

with

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
```

If you remove `"application/json"`,the header will be `application/xml; charset=utf-8`,or it will be `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: still, the same error, `[Produces]` is just a function to select the specific type of response you want in my understanding